# sendEmptyMessageAtTime issue

Tags: android

A handler that I defined doesn't get a message set with sendEmptyMessageAtTime. The time I get from updateTime.getTimeInMillis is valid. What am I missing here ?

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mNavigationBarFragment.configureFor(0);
    Calendar updateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    updateTime.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2012);
    updateTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18);
    updateTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 40);
    updateTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    if(mUpdateOnAirLabel.sendEmptyMessageAtTime(1, updateTime.getTimeInMillis())){
    // messages gets placed
    }
}

private Handler mUpdateOnAirLabel = new Handler() {
    public void dispatchMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
    // doesn't get triggered
}

public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
    // doesn't get triggered
}
};
```

**UPD**
The time I get from the calendar object is right:

```
<?php

echo date("r", 1348753200578 / 1000);
```

output: Thu, 27 Sep 2012 17:40:00 +0400

After that I've tried to offset from the current timestamp

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance(); 
long nowt = now.getTimeInMillis();
if(mUpdateOnAirLabel.sendEmptyMessageAtTime(1, now.getTimeInMillis() + 5000)){
        ...
}
```

And it's not triggering either. What's wrong here ?

Comment: read the sendEmptyMessageAtTime documentation

Comment: "Sends a Message containing only the what value, to be delivered at a specific time." so what ?

Comment: so, the parameter is uptimeMillis. A little further in the documentation, it says : " The time-base is uptimeMillis()" see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#uptimeMillis()

Comment: so, what you say is that I can't use Calendar with this method ? How should I schedule the alarm then ? With offset from the uptimeMillis() ?

Comment: precisely. use uptimeMillis instead of the now.getTimeInMillis()

Answer (score -1):

You didn't specify the day! put Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR or something like that!

Comment: Not sure whether it will work because the time I get from the calendar object is right, however I handler ain't working;

Comment: no need to specify the day, as the getInstance from calendar returns a calendar using the current time.